# Запись пациентов в таблицу

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Делаю примитивное приложение для измерения некоторого параметра и записи пациентов с реузльтатом в таблицу. Возникли трудности.

1. Как по нажатию кнопки "записать", выполнилось создание таблички со столбцами с названиями как в форме "id"? Нужно, чтобы таблица в отдельном окне появилась. Читал про `QTableWidgets`, но пока дикая каша в голове.
2. Также по нажатию кнопки результат подсчета должен высветиться в области между "конц" и "ммоль" (для этого я сделал виджет, но оставил пустым, в коде он упоминается как `resfin`, может это можно реализовать как-то)
3. Ну и, пожалуй, высший для меня пока пилотаж, мне нужно чтобы результат заносился в ту же таблицу в 4-ый столбец, но чтобы 4 столбец заполнялся независимо от первых трех (которые про id)
   таблица по задумке должна заполняться как скрине.

`calculation` - модулёк из 4 строчек, который считает ту самую концентрацию.
Оставляю код, надеюсь на помощь, совет, открыт для сотрудничества

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from Calculation import calc
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

#создание графики кнопок
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")        
    self.CalcButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.CalcButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 211, 71))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.CalcButton.setFont(font)
    self.CalcButton.setObjectName("CalcButton")
    self.idpat = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.idpat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 571, 191))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.idpat.setFont(font)
    self.idpat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.idpat.setObjectName("idpat")
    self.nam = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.idpat)
    self.nam.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 45, 80, 30))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.nam.setFont(font)
    self.nam.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.nam.setObjectName("nam")
    self.nameed = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.idpat)
    self.nameed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 400, 40))
    self.nameed.setObjectName("nameed")
    self.birdat = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.idpat)
    self.birdat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 95, 131, 30))
    self.birdat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.birdat.setObjectName("birdat")
    self.gend = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.idpat)
    self.gend.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 145, 80, 30))
    self.gend.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.gend.setObjectName("gend")
    self.combox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.idpat)
    self.combox1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 51, 40))
    self.combox1.setObjectName("combox1")
    self.combox1.addItem("")
    self.combox1.addItem("")
    self.birdated = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.idpat)
    self.birdated.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 121, 40))
    self.birdated.setObjectName("birdated")
    self.glucon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.glucon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 430, 231, 51))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.glucon.setFont(font)
    self.glucon.setObjectName("glucon")
    self.regButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.regButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 240, 141, 28))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.regButton.setFont(font)
    self.regButton.setObjectName("regButton")
    self.mmol = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.mmol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 430, 91, 51))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.mmol.setFont(font)
    self.mmol.setObjectName("mmol")
    self.resfin = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.resfin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 440, 131, 41))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.resfin.setFont(font)
    self.resfin.setText("")
    self.resfin.setObjectName("resfin")
    
    #создание менюбара
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.action_4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.action_4.setObjectName("action_4")
    self.exit1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.exit1.setObjectName("exit1")
    self.menu.addAction(self.action_4)
    self.menu.addAction(self.exit1)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
    

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    
    

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    
    #кнопки


    #кнопка измерения
    self.CalcButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать измерение"))
    self.idpat.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ID Пациента"))
    self.nam.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ФИО"))
    self.nameed.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ФИО пациента"))
    self.birdat.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
    self.gend.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
    self.combox1.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите пол"))
    self.combox1.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "М"))
    self.combox1.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Ж"))
    self.birdated.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите дату рождения пациента"))
    self.glucon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Концентрация Глюкозы:"))
    self.mmol.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ммоль/л"))
    self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Меню"))
    self.regButton.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить инфо о пациенте"))
    self.regButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Записать"))
    
   
    
    #функция записи


    #действия менюбара
    #справка
    self.action_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Справка"))
    self.action_4.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Узнать об авторах")) #сообщение в левом нижнем углу
    self.action_4.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+I")) #shortcut дает возможность назначить комбинацию кнопок
    self.action_4.triggered.connect(self.infowindow)

    #выход из программы
    self.exit1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
    self.exit1.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Выйти из программы"))
    self.exit1.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+Shift+Q"))
    self.exit1.triggered.connect(self.exitapp)

#функция выхода из программы
def exitapp(self):
    QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()

#функция об авторах

def infowindow(self):
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setWindowTitle("Справка")
    msg.setText("")
    x = msg.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал много комментариев в тексте. 
Попробуйте изучить и понять написанное.
Что будет не понятно -спросите, но после изучения программы.

Некоторые советы:

- **НИКОГДА** Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА!**. 
  Создайте другой класс, 
  который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
- Для ввода строки используйте QLineEdit, а не QTextEdit
- Вы должны понимать, что какие-либо расчеты применительны к конкретному пациенту.

Удачи вам.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

#from Calculation import calc   # ?


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    #создание графики 
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")        
        self.CalcButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CalcButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 211, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.CalcButton.setFont(font)
        self.CalcButton.setObjectName("CalcButton")
        self.idpat = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.idpat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 571, 191))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.idpat.setFont(font)
        self.idpat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.idpat.setObjectName("idpat")
        self.nam = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.idpat)
        self.nam.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 45, 80, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.nam.setFont(font)
        self.nam.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.nam.setObjectName("nam")
#!!! QLineEdit      
        self.nameed = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.idpat)                            # - QTextEdit(self.idpat)

        self.nameed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 400, 40))
        self.nameed.setObjectName("nameed")
        self.birdat = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.idpat)
        self.birdat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 95, 131, 30))
        self.birdat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.birdat.setObjectName("birdat")
        self.gend = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.idpat)
        self.gend.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 145, 80, 30))
        self.gend.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.gend.setObjectName("gend")
        self.combox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.idpat)
        self.combox1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 51, 40))
        self.combox1.setObjectName("combox1")
        self.combox1.addItem("")
        self.combox1.addItem("")
        self.birdated = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.idpat)
        self.birdated.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 121, 40))
        self.birdated.setObjectName("birdated")
        self.glucon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.glucon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 430, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.glucon.setFont(font)
        self.glucon.setObjectName("glucon")
        self.regButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.regButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 240, 141, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.regButton.setFont(font)
        self.regButton.setObjectName("regButton")
        self.mmol = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.mmol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 430, 91, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.mmol.setFont(font)
        self.mmol.setObjectName("mmol")

        self.resfin = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.resfin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 440, 131, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.resfin.setFont(font)
        self.resfin.setText("")
        self.resfin.setObjectName("resfin")

        #создание менюбара
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.action_4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_4.setObjectName("action_4")
        self.exit1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.exit1.setObjectName("exit1")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_4)
        self.menu.addAction(self.exit1)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.CalcButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать измерение"))
        self.idpat.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ID Пациента"))
        self.nam.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ФИО"))
        self.nameed.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ФИО пациента"))
        self.birdat.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.gend.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
        self.combox1.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите пол"))
        self.combox1.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "М"))
        self.combox1.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Ж"))
        self.birdated.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите дату рождения пациента"))
        self.glucon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Концентрация Глюкозы:"))
        self.mmol.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ммоль/л"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Меню"))
        self.regButton.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить инфо о пациенте"))
        self.regButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Записать"))

        self.action_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Справка"))
        self.action_4.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Узнать об авторах")) #сообщение в левом нижнем углу
        self.action_4.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+I")) #shortcut дает возможность назначить комбинацию кнопок
        #выход из программы
        self.exit1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.exit1.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Выйти из программы"))
        self.exit1.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+Shift+Q"))


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):                                        # наследуем QTableWidget
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 450, 200))

        # setRowCount(int) устанавливает количество строк в таблице, 
        # а setColumnCount(int) устанавливает количество столбцов.
        # или вы можете напрямую указать количество строк и столбцов во время создания экземпляра;
        self.setRowCount(1)                                                
        self.setColumnCount(4)

        # setColumnWidth(int, int) устанавливает ширину столбца,
        #   первый параметр заполняет номер столбца, а 
        #   второй параметр заполняет значение ширины.
        # setRowCount(int, int) устанавливает высоту строки, параметры одинаковы;
        self.setColumnWidth(0,130)                                             
        self.setRowHeight(0, 30)

        # setHorizontalHeaderLabels(iterable) устанавливает заголовок строки, а 
        # setVerticalHeaderLabels устанавливает заголовок столбца;
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ФИО', 'Дата рождения', 'пол', 'результат']) 

        # Создайте экземпляр ячейки и добавьте ячейку в таблицу с помощью
        # setItem(int, int, QTableWidgetItem).
        # Первые два параметра типа int - это номер строки и номер столбца; 
        self.item_1 = QTableWidgetItem('Иванов И.И.')                           
        self.setItem(0, 0, self.item_1)
        # или так
        self.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('01.01.1990'))
        self.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem('м'))


# Создаем класс для Главного окна
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)  

        self.allButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Показать', self)
        self.allButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 260, 141, 28))

        self.allButton.clicked.connect(self.all_button)
        self.CalcButton.clicked.connect(self.calc_button)
        self.regButton.clicked.connect(self.reg_button)

        self.action_4.triggered.connect(self.infowindow)
        self.exit1.triggered.connect(self.exitapp)

        self.tableWidget = TableWidget()

    #функция выхода из программы
    def exitapp(self):
        self.close()

    def infowindow(self):
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Справка', 'Справка Справка Справка\nСправка Справка')

    def all_button(self):
        self.tableWidget.show()

    def reg_button(self):
        if not self.nameed.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Введите ФИО')
            return
        # rowCount() получает количество строк, а columnCount() получает количество столбцов; 
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()  
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(self.nameed.text()))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(self.birdated.text()))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(self.combox1.currentText()))  

        self.nameed.clear()        

    def calc_button(self):
        if not len(self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()):
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Вы не выбрали пациента для расчета')
            return

        # тут делайте свои подсчеты 

        text = 'результат подсчета'
        self.resfin.setText(text) 

        row = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()[0].row()
        print(row)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 3, QTableWidgetItem(text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы мой герой! Большое спасибо за замечания! Запустить получилось, сейчас посканю код глазами. Обязательно отпишусь по вопросам!